# Sunspot automaticly escape special characters

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Using sunspot and solr 4+ is there a way to automatically escape special characters.

For example in a simple fulltext search like:

```
Post.search do
  fulltext term
end
```

If the `term` contains any of the special chars (http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Regexp_Searches) then they should be auto escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your initializers file add following code

```
RE_ESCAPE_SOLR = /([-+!\(\)\{\}\[\]^"~*?:\\]|&&|\|\|)/

class String
  def escape_solr
    gsub(RE_ESCAPE_SOLR) { |e| "\\#{e}" }
  end
end
```

and whenever searching for anything you can just call

```
Post.search do
  fulltext term.escape_solr
end
```

Comment: This is my current work around, only I prefer refinements, but I was hoping there is a build in way to do it.